# Convert JSONArray to Vector on a BlackBerry

Tags: json, blackberry, java-me

I am able to convert a bytestream to its JSON representation.  This is a JSONArray.  I would like it to be converted to `bb_test` objects in a Vector instead.  How do I do that?

I used this example of json
http://codeoncloud.blogspot.com/2013/05/blackberry-java-json-tutorial.html

I am getting data from server like this:

```
[
    {
        "settingName": "New",
        "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"
    },
    {
        "settingName": "Open",
        "settingValue": "OpenDoc()"
    },
    {
        "settingName": "Close",
        "settingValue": "CloseDoc()"
    }
]
```

So I create a class like that

```
package mypackage;

public class bb_test {
    String settingName;
    /**
     * 
     */
    String settingValue;
    public String getSettingName() {
        return settingName;
    }
    public void setSettingName(String settingName) {
        this.settingName = settingName;
    }
    public String getSettingValue() {
        return settingValue;
    }
    public void setSettingValue(String settingValue) {
        this.settingValue = settingValue;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, store these parameters in two string arrays named `settingNameArray` and `settingValueArray` where you are receiving this JSON data.  Something like this

Suppose your whole JSON is received in the following Array, then

```
JSONArray arr=new JSONArray(jsonData);
int size=arr.length();
String[] settingNameArray=new String[size];
String[] settingValueArray=new String[size];
JSONObject[] obj=new JSONObject[size];
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    settingNameArray[i]=arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("settingName");
    settingValueArray[i]=arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("settingValue");
}

bb_test.setSettingValue(settingValueArray);
bb_test.setSettingName(settingNameArray);
```

After that, change your class structure of bb_test to save these values. It will look something like this

```
public class bb_test {
    String settingName[];
    String settingValue[];
    public bb_test ()
    {   
    }
    public String[] getSettingName() {
        return settingName;
    }
    public void setSettingName(String[] settingName) {
        this.settingName = settingName;
    }
    public String[] getSettingValue() {
        return settingValue;
    }
    public void setSettingValue(String[] settingValue) {
        this.settingValue = settingValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like he wants one `bb_test` object to represent one pair of setting and value.  Not a pair of *arrays*.

Answer (score 0):

Your bb_test class is fine, no need to change it, except maybe the naming convention. You can get an array from the data like this :

```
Vector bb_testVector = new Vector();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonData);
int size = jsonArray.length();

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        JSONObject tempJSON = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        String settingName = tempJSON.getString("settingName");
        String settingValue = tempJSON.getString("settingValue");

        bb_test newBBTest = new bb_test();
        newBBTest.setSettingName(settingName);
        newBBTest.setSettingValue(settingValue);

        bb_testVector.addElement(newBBTest);

        //clean memory
        tempJSON = null;
        newBBTest = null;
        settingName = null;
        settingValue = null;
    }
```